# OpenCL: getting OUT_OF_RESOURCES error from clFlush

Tags: c, parallel-processing, opencl, gpu

Required size is much smaller than global size so it looks like my device has enough memory. Why do I get that error?

Required size: 39819160
Global size: 1709598311
Local size: 65536

The kernel has a printf statement but it doesnt print anything so I guess the kernel is ok. It works with small data at least.

The same code works great on another computer with Intel HD 430 that has much bigger global size limit.

I run this code over and over again with the same context and device_id.
It fails on the first iteration.

```
void check_errors(cl_int err) {
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS) {
        cerr << err << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
}

int SVM::fit(cl_float* x, cl_uint weight_size, cl_float* y, cl_uint data_size, cl_float h, cl_uint T) {
    cl_int err;

    if (data_size == 0 )
        return 0;
    set(x, weight_size, data_size);

    cl_uint* a = (cl_uint*)calloc(data_size, sizeof(cl_uint));
    cl_uint indices[T];
    for(size_t t = 0; t < T; t++)
        indices[t] = rand() % data_size;

    const char* src = "/*float kernel_func(__global float* x, __global float* b, size_t size) {\n"
            "    float s = 0;\n"
            "    while( size > 0 ) {\n"
            "        size--;\n"
            "        s += x[size] * b[size];\n"
            "    }\n"
            "\n"
            "    return s;\n"
            "}\n"
            "\n"
            "\n*/"
            "__kernel void fit(__global uint* indices, uint T, __global uint* a, __global float* x, uint weight_size, __global float* y, uint data_size, float h) {\n"
            "    /*uint id = get_global_id(0);\n"
            "    if (id >= T)\n"
            "        return;\n"
            "\n"
            "    uint t =  id + 1;\n"
            "    uint i = indices[id];\n"
            "\n"
            "    float q = 1/(h*t);\n"
            "    float s = 0;\n"
            "\n"
            "    for(int j = 0; j < data_size; j++)\n"
            "     if( j != i ) {\n"
            "         s += a[j] * y[j] * kernel_func(&x[i * weight_size], &x[j * weight_size], weight_size);\n"
            "     }\n"
            "\n"
            "    if (y[i] * q * s < 1) {\n"
            "     atomic_add(&a[i], 1);\n"
            "    }\n"
            "*/}\n";

    cl_command_queue cmd_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &err);
    check_errors(err);

    cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, &src, NULL, &err);
    check_errors(err);

    if( clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) != CL_SUCCESS ) {
        char log[999999];
        clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, 999999, log, NULL);
        cerr << log << endl;
        std::exit(-1);
        return -1;
    }



    cl_kernel opencl_kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "fit", &err);
    check_errors(err);

    size_t total_size = 0;
    total_size += sizeof(cl_uint) * data_size;
    cl_mem a_buffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(cl_uint) * data_size, a, &err);
    check_errors(err);

    total_size += sizeof(cl_float) * weight_size * data_size;
    cl_mem x_buffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(cl_float) * weight_size * data_size, x, &err);
    check_errors(err);

    total_size += sizeof(cl_float) * data_size;
    cl_mem y_buffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(cl_float) * data_size, y, &err);
    check_errors(err);

    total_size += sizeof(cl_uint) * T;
    cl_mem indices_buffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(cl_uint) * T, indices, &err);

    cout << "Required size: " << total_size << endl;

    cl_ulong size;
    err = clGetDeviceInfo(device_id, CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE, sizeof(cl_ulong), &size, 0);
    check_errors(err);
    cout << "Global size: " << size << endl;

    //cl_ulong size;
    err = clGetDeviceInfo(device_id, CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE, sizeof(cl_ulong), &size, 0);
    check_errors(err);
    cout << "Local size: " << size << endl;

    err = clSetKernelArg(opencl_kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &indices_buffer);
    check_errors(err);
    err = clSetKernelArg(opencl_kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_uint), &T);
    check_errors(err);
    err = clSetKernelArg(opencl_kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &a_buffer);
    check_errors(err);
    err = clSetKernelArg(opencl_kernel, 3, sizeof(cl_mem), &x_buffer);
    check_errors(err);
    err = clSetKernelArg(opencl_kernel, 4, sizeof(cl_uint), &weight_size);
    check_errors(err);
    err = clSetKernelArg(opencl_kernel, 5, sizeof(cl_mem), &y_buffer);
    check_errors(err);
    err = clSetKernelArg(opencl_kernel, 6, sizeof(cl_uint), &data_size);
    check_errors(err);
    err = clSetKernelArg(opencl_kernel, 7, sizeof(cl_float), &h);
    check_errors(err);

    size_t localWorkSize = 16 ;
    size_t numWorkGroups = (T + localWorkSize - 1) / localWorkSize;
    size_t globalWorkSize = numWorkGroups * localWorkSize;

    err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cmd_queue, opencl_kernel, 1, NULL, &globalWorkSize, &localWorkSize, 0, NULL, NULL);
    check_errors(err);

    err = clFinish(cmd_queue);
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS) {
        cerr << endl;
        cerr << err << endl;
        cout << "Data size: " << data_size << endl;
        cout << "Weight size: " << weight_size << endl;

        /*for(int i = 0; i < data_size; i++) {
            for(int yi = 0; yi < 28; yi++) {
                for(int xi = 0; xi < 28; xi++) {
                    if (x[i * weight_size + yi*28 + xi] == 0)
                        cout << " ";
                    else
                        cout << "*";
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
            cout << (int)y[i] << endl;

        }*/

        exit(-1);
    }

    clReleaseMemObject(indices_buffer);
    clReleaseMemObject(a_buffer);
    clReleaseMemObject(x_buffer);
    clReleaseMemObject(y_buffer);
    clReleaseKernel(opencl_kernel);
    clReleaseProgram(program);
    clReleaseCommandQueue(cmd_queue);





    float q = 1/(h*T);
    v = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * data_size);
    for(size_t j = 0; j < data_size; j++) {
        v[j] = q * a[j] * y[j];
    }

    w = (float*) calloc(weight_size, sizeof(float));
    float cur_x[weight_size];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < data_size; i++) {
        memcpy(cur_x, &x[i * weight_size], weight_size * sizeof(float));
        produce_vector(cur_x, weight_size, v[i]);
        add_to_vector(w, cur_x, weight_size);
    }
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code you wish to post?

Comment: Sure. But I care more about if my gpu is able to allocate the required data.

Comment: Have you tried removing all `printf`'s from your kernel and run it again? Depending on the version of OpenCL installed or the vendor `printf` may be not supported or buggy. If that doesn't change anything then post your kernel code. Also check for errors when calling `clSetKernelArg`.

Comment: I put printf to make sure if it gets into the kernel. It gets out_of_resources without printf as well :(

clSetKernelArg works without any errors.

Comment: I've looked at the kernel but can't see anything suspicious there. Next step would be to check for out of bound array access. Some GPUs are sensitive to that other not meaning one GPU may not return any error, even results may accidentally be correct but the other won't work with such code. That is usually the difference on the vendor level. You may also want to comment out part of the code and run it to narrow down the problem to specific part or line of code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I commented out the body of the kernel fit function. Still have the same error.

Comment: Have you actually checked if OpenCL works OK on that GPU using any simple example? If so then you need to check every OpenCL function call on the host side, if it doesn't return any error. I don't know if you simplified your code snippet before pasting it here but OpenCL function calls before clEnqueueNDRangeKernel aren't checked for errors except for the build one.

Comment: I tested OpenCL with matrix multiplication. It works correctly. 
Yeah, I simplified it. Now I posted full code there. Looks like all opencl function calls are checked. Error comes from clFinish only.

Comment: Your global size can be too big. Have you checked ´CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES´ and ´CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE´? If they are too small `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` should fail, but maybe there is a bug in the driver.